# iOS hide Touch ID after view controller disappears

Tags: ios, iphone, modalviewcontroller, touch-id, lacontext

I show Touch ID in my Passcode View Controller (it's presented as modal view controller) by  `context.evaluatePolicy(LAPolicy.deviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics, localizedReason: message`

But sometimes I need to dismiss Passcode View Controller programatically before user enters his fingerprint. In this case alert with touch ID stays on its place. How can I dismiss this Touch ID alert too?

Comment: You want to dismiss the Passcode ViewController when TouchId alertVC is present, right?

Comment: @NiravD, yes, and I want TouchID to disappear too  after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare

```
LAContext *myContext;
if ([myContext canEvaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics error:&authError]) {
    [myContext evaluatePolicy:LAPolicyDeviceOwnerAuthenticationWithBiometrics
              localizedReason:myLocalizedReasonString
                        reply:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                            if (success) {
} else {
}];
```

add this line where do you  want to  dismiss touch id view

```
    [myContext invalidate];
```

Comment: I can't check right now, but I think that it should work, so I mark it as correct